# How can I auto-redirect a user after they share a post on Facebook

Tags: html, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, redirect

I have a button on my website allowing the users to share the site on Facebook. 
The button has the following anchor tag:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.com.au

This redirects the user to a site where they can post on their Facebook Page. Once the user click's 'Post', Facebook automatically redirects the user to a blank page which has the following in the address bar.

[https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close#_=_)

I want to direct the user to my own custom website rather than the blank Facebook default.

A quick Google search on this issues suggested that I need to add a redirect parameter in the URL so that Facebook knows where to redirect the user once they complete the post. It is meant to look like this:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.com.au&redirect_uri=http://newsite.com

As you can see, I have added the parameter "redirect_uri" and I have set it to: htttp://newsite.com

Only one small problem.....

It doesnt work!

I have no idea why, but it still directs to the default blank page (https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.com.au)

I have tried clearing my browser cache, I have tried different browsers, I have even tried multiple devices but I still can't get this to work.

Am I doing something wrong? Did Facebook deprecate this feature?

FYI: This is where I found to use the redirect parameter: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: _“This is where I found to use the redirect parameter:”_ - the URL to trigger the share dialog there is a different one, it is not `/sharer/sharer.php` ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it doesn't return to the correct URL, but I had a similar problem and created the below solution:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fbShareWindowOpen()">
  <span id="fbShareButton">Share this on facebook!</span>
</a>
<script>
  function fbShareWindowOpen() {
    var myWindow = window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.url-to-share.com/", "", "top=30px,width=200,height=100");
  }
</script>
```

This will open up a window that will resize correctly to fit the facebook sharer UI. When the link is shared (the share button has been clicked) the new window closes, making for a very clean flow.

I don't know for sure, but I assume the facebook sharer child window is closed by the "..return/close.." redirect URL.